# jquery multiple img filling fixed height container with same width

Tags: jquery, image, image-resizing

I was sure this problem was easy to solve, but after hours of searching, I finaly post here to find some help.

I have a fixed height and width container, let's consider as a large column.

There  are 3 images displayed on it, with diferents size. Size can change.

I'd like the images resizing to fill the column vertically (no need to fill horizontally), and getting all the same width. (for a "column" look)

I found a jquery plugin solution for doing this horizontally : jpictura.
It takes the 3 pictures, and display them as large as possible, with the same height, for filling exactly the row.

But now I'm searching the same, but for vertical instead of horizontal.

Let's imagine a container of 1000px height, and 800px max-width.
And 3 images to display on it :
img1 : 800px * 1600px
img2 : 300px * 800px, 
img3 : 1800px * 1600px

My logical would say to me to follow those steps (in jquery) :

1. calculate the total height of the 3 images when they are 100% width of their container.
2. Calculate how much purcent we must reduce the total height for it fit on the container height.
3. Reduce each image size according to this purcentage.

But I'm full of doubt...

And maybe a jquery plugin exists for doing this in a clean and stable way. But it's just me who was unable to find it ? 
Or worst ! I find it and try it, but was unable to use it the good way.. ^^

Any idea ?

Thanks

[edit]Here's some exemples to show what I'd like to do. The images ake taking 100% height of their container, they all have the same width, without loosing ratio.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of imagining the situation, it would be better if you were to re-create the example with HTML/CSS/JavaScript so that we can see what you have and help you.

Comment: Can you clarify your end-desired result? You want all three images to be identical height/width? With the height filling the height of the container? Do you care about the images being distorted or are you expecting the images to be shown only partially? Like @automaton, you should give us some code to work with. You can use http://placehold.it to provide images for the example.

Comment: Thansk for answering, sorry for the lack of details...
The ratio must be respect.
No need for the images to have the same height (cause I want kept ratio)
Need for the images to have the same width (column "look").
I prefer if images are shown totally, but if sometimes a little part is hidden, it's ok.
I'm gonna prepare some few images to illustrate my question. I'll be back ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally wrote a little script, not so hard finally :)

I guess the function can be optimized, I'm not a specialist for jquery...
Anyway it does the job for me : take all the images, give them the same width, and make them fit the total height of the column.
A precision : in my case, I used it to display nicely photos on a PDF, so I got fixed width and height values corresponding to my A4 pdf content.
It works whatever number of images you try to display.

JS :

```
function setImagesToFillAColumn() {
    var maxWidth = 735;
    var totalHeight = 0;
    var availableHeight = 980;

    //set all images to this max width and calculate total height
    $('.pdf-a-column-images-container > img').each(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height
        var ratio = height / width;
        var newHeight = maxWidth * ratio;
        $(this).removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height"); // Remove HTML attributes
        $(this).css("height", newHeight+'px').css("width", maxWidth+'px'); // change css attributes
        totalHeight = totalHeight + newHeight;
    });

    //calculate the reduction purcentage neddded for all the images fit to the row
    var purcentageReduction = availableHeight / totalHeight;

    if (purcentageReduction < 1) {
        //reduce to this purcentage for all image size
        $('.pdf-a-column-images-container > img').each(function(){
            var finalHeight = $(this).height() * purcentageReduction;
            var finalWidth = $(this).width() * purcentageReduction;
            $(this).css("height", finalHeight+'px').css("width", finalWidth+'px'); // change css attributes
        });
    }
}
```

And html, quite simple :

```
<div class="pdf-a-column-images-container">
    <img src="urltoimg1" />
    <img src="urltoimg2" />
    <img src="urltoimg3" />
    <img src="urltoimg4" />
</div>
```

For another use, I made the same function, but to fit images on a row (horizontally) instead of a column.
It displays the images I give in a single row, with the same height, taking 100% of the row.

JS :

```
function setImagesToFillARow() {
    var maxHeight = null;
    var totalWidth = 0;
    var availableWidth = 735;
    //get the less high image height
    $('.pdf-a-row-images-container > img').each(function(){
        if (maxHeight === null || $(this).height() < maxHeight ) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
    });

    //set all images to this height and calculate total width
    $('.pdf-a-row-images-container > img').each(function(){
        var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
        var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height
        var ratio = height / width;
        var newWidth = maxHeight / ratio;
        $(this).removeAttr("width").removeAttr("height"); // Remove HTML attributes
        $(this).css("width", newWidth+'px').css("height", maxHeight+'px'); // change css attributes
        totalWidth = totalWidth + newWidth;
    });

    //calculate the reduction purcentage neddded for all the images fit to the row
    var purcentageReduction = availableWidth / totalWidth;
    var finalHeight = maxHeight * purcentageReduction;
    //set images container to the new height
    $('.pdf-a-row-images-container').css('height', finalHeight+'px');

    //reduce to this purcentage all image size
    $('.pdf-a-row-images-container > img').each(function(){
        var finalWidth = $(this).width() * purcentageReduction;
        $(this).css("width", finalWidth+'px').css("height", finalHeight+'px'); // change css attributes
    });
}
```

And the html :

```
<div class="pdf-a-row-images-container">
    <img src="urltoimg1" />
    <img src="urltoimg2" />
    <img src="urltoimg3" />
    <img src="urltoimg4" />
</div>
```

And for finish, fewcss rules, used for column and row display :

```
.pdf-a-row-images-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 3px;
}
.pdf-a-column-images-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    line-height: 1px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.pdf-a-column-images-container img {
    display: block;
    margin: 1px auto;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I know it's far from being perfect, but if it can helps :)